# MYSQL I need to first sort by a column and then limit the results based on a number of times a value appears in another column/columns

Tags: mysql, count, limit

First, I am an extreme noob when it comes to posting on here, and with MYSQL, so I apologize for any format or syntax errors.

Take the below table.

| name1 | name2 | widgets |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Johnny | Suzie | 3 |
| Johnny | Tommy | 5 |
| Anna | Suzie | 2 |
| Johnny | Billy | 7 |
| Anna | Billy | 9 |

I need to sort by "widgets" first, and then limit results to where a name appears a maximum of 2 times in the name1 column, and a maximum of 1 time in the name2 column. So the result would be

| name1 | name2 | widgets |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Anna | Billy | 9 |
| Johnny | Tommy | 5 |
| Johnny | Suzie | 3 |

I've found several articles on here about getting counts but they don't seem to meet my specific needs. They all just give me a calculated total.  I would assume I need to use some combination of  the `COUNT` and `LIMIT` functions but I can't quite figure out where to start. If any more info is needed please let me know. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a common table expression `CTE` to assign a `row_number` to the name1 and name2 columns. Then select from the CTE and use `where` to only select rows where the row_number is <= 2 or = 1.

```
with t1 as (
SELECT name1, name2, widgets, 
      row_number( ) over( partition by name1 order by widgets ) name1_row_num
FROM widgetTable 
    )
select name1, name2, widgets
from   t1  
where   name1_row_num <= 2 
order by widgets
```

Comment: @RrockBoro that worked great just had to change the "widgetTable" to T1.  However, how can I do th second column the same way?  Can I do it in the same query?